# Two missing tarot cards in Cyberpunk 2077?

Tags: cyberpunk-2077

Where can I find the two missing tarots in Cyberpunk 2077? The quest *"The Fool on the Hill"* gives us coordinates for all tarot graffities but two of them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So the last two Tarot cards are "The Devil" and "Judgement."

Once you're on the "point of no return," the Judgement mural can be found in Arasaka Tower, after defeating Adam Smasher:

[image: Judgement]

The Devil is harder to achieve, and only available if you go with Hanako's plan.  Essentially,

> V has a nightmare in Arasaka HQ while trying to solve a rubic's cube type puzzle.  It breaks, and the Devil card is inside of it.

Answer (score 5):

The last two tarot cards are only scan-able in the final missions of the game (past "the point of no return"). I believe if you reload your save after beating the game you can keep the scanned tarots in your journal (the same way you can keep Rogue's gun, the Aldecaldos Jacket, and Adam Smasher's Access card).

For what it's worth, you don't need the final two to complete the "Fool on the Hill" quest.